# What is the expectation of the product of 2 random variables (Gauss-Markov assumptions)?

Tags: least-squares, econometrics, expected-value, blue

In the two variable (intercept and slope) model:

[image]

among other, one of the Gauss-Markov assumptions is (in the BLUE framework of OLS)

[image]

My coarse slides state this implies that there is no correlation between the error term `u` and `X`. And the proof is this:

[image]

What concerns me is the case where `X` is stochastic. 
What I don't understand is how the expectation of a product becomes the expectation of `u` given `X` over all possible `X` values.

I would expect to see this:

[image]

at the very least because we are interested in a product. Am I wrong to think this and why so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)

Comment: This was very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E(XY)=E(E(XY|X))=E(XE(Y|X))$$

$$E(X_i \mu_i)=E \left( E(X_i \mu_i|X_i) \right)=E \left(X_i E( \mu_i|X_i) \right)=E(X_i 0)=0$$